# How do you input values and strings into class array through a method class?

Tags: java, arrays, class, vector

When I try to add a contact information through addContact method, it should prompt me to input name, phone number, and address. Then the information is stored on the class array.

When addContact is triggered, it gives off:

```
Contact[] contacts;
    public void addContact(Contact c)
    {
        String name = "";
        long number = 0000000000;
        String comment = "";
        if(isFull());
        incrementCapacity();
        size++;
        for (int i = 0; i <= contacts.length; i++)
        {
            if(contacts[i] == null)
            {
                contacts[i].setName(name);
                contacts[i].setPhoneNumber(number);
                contacts[i].setComment(comment);
            }

        }
    }
```

Instead it gives off the error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at VectorOfContacts.addContact(VectorOfContacts.java:71)
    at Driver2.main(Driver2.java:20)
```

Line 71 is if(contacts[i] ==null). If I delete the if statement. It will happen with the rest of the three lines below it as well.

What is the proper way to ensure that the inputs is placed into the class as an array?

Comment: I posted my answer did you slove your issue?

Comment: Yes it has however, what I really meant to ask is if there's a way to input string into a class object

Comment: can you tell me what you really mean to input string into a class object?

Comment: A class object contains name, phone number and a comment. What I'm trying to do is when I add to the contact object, I use the string, long, and string input respectively to add to the object array.

Comment: what you did is right

Comment: It compiles properly however, whatever I input will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is in below line:

```
 for (int i = 0; i <= contacts.length; i++)
```

index in `Java` starts from `0` to less than length which is `contacts.length-1` ,so variable `i` inside your for loop must be less than `contacts.length`

Change to:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop is a little buggy here:

```
    for (int i = 0; i <= contacts.length; i++)
```

You are iterating till i <= contacts.length. Arrays index run from `0` to `length-1`. So you need to change your loop to:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

In java indexing start from 0 but length start from 1. So you should update Condition in for loop to

```
i<contacts.length
```

I hope you have initialize and filled the array by empty Contact Items and if you filled it with Contact Items 'contact[i]==null' is wrong. Then you should look for inside contact[i] object like this.

```
contacts[i].getName().equals("") && contacts[i].getNumber().equals("") && contacts[i].getNumber()==0000000000
```

. Otherwise Use like this

```
Contact[] contact=new Contact[3]

public void Add(Contact c){
     for(int i=0;i<contact.length;i++){
         if(contact[i]==null){
                contact[i]=c;
          }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java, counting the length of an array is starting from 1. But counting the index of an element is starting from 0. It means that, think you have an array with 10 elements,
Length of the array is 10
Index of the 1st element is 0
Index of the last element is 9

According to your code, you are trying to access with contacts[length]th element, but index of last element is contacts[length - 1]. That is why you get a "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException".

Change the for-loop as,
 for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++)

Good Luck!!!!!!